# In AWS Cognito, is it possible for an external provider login to setup MFA?

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, two-factor-authentication

I have setup two factor authentication with the aws-amplify javascript library. With users who sign up with a simple email and password, it works great. I do something like

```
const user = await Auth.signIn(username, password);

 if (user.challengeName === 'SMS_MFA') ...
```

However, when a user signs in with an external provider (let's say Google for example) and they enable MFA, the `challengeName` returned is not `SMS_MFA`. It comes back as `USER_SRP_AUTH`.

I'm wondering if I'm not doing something right, or if you just can't setup MFA for external provider logins for some reason? I've looked everywhere for the answer to this question and can't seem to find anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering the same thing but my circumstances are somewhat different.

I have discovered that users which come from the external provider (these users are in the confirmation status External Provider) can not login using the CUSTOM_AUTHENTICATION. I have setup a custom authentication flow using OTP codes sent via SMS which does not trigger for users which come from the external provider.

Edit: Most likely, MFA and CUSTOM_AUTHENTICATION are disabled for users which come from the external provider.

I have seen [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-identity-federation-consolidate-users.html) that the possible solution may be `Account Linking`, but I am yet to confirm this.